# How to pass hashmap json data to JQPlot?

Tags: jquery, json, jqplot

I need to pass the json hash map data to the jqplot, i dont want to convert the json object to array and pass to jqplot. Is it possible to pass the hashmap json to jqplot? The hashmap contains string and map of values. Like this

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> data;
```

Can anyone please suggest some ideas to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page
http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Our ajax data renderer which here retrieves a text file.
  // it could contact any source and pull data, however.
  // The options argument isn't used in this renderer.
  var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
    var ret = null;
    $.ajax({
      // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
      // will return before the data is fetched
      async: false,
      url: url,
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data) {
        ret = data;
      }
    });
    return ret;
  };

  // The url for our json data
  var jsonurl = "./jsondata.txt";

  // passing in the url string as the jqPlot data argument is a handy
  // shortcut for our renderer.  You could also have used the
  // "dataRendererOptions" option to pass in the url.
  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl,{
    title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
    dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
    dataRendererOptions: {
      unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
    }
  });
});
```